# Проблема с обработчиком сообщений aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, aiogram-2.x

Пишу бота в тг, возникла проблема с обработчиком сообщений

```
@dp.message_handler(Text(equals=['Arizona RP', 'GTA5 RP']), state=Form.PROJECT)
async def input_nick(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    project = message.text
    print(project)
    await state.update_data(project=project)
    await message.answer('Введите ваш ник в формате: Имя_Фамилия', reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())
```

кнопка

```
cmd_arizona = types.KeyboardButton(text='Arizona RP')
```

После нажатия на кнопку Arizona RP бот должен отправлять сообщение с просьбой ввести ник, но ничего не отправляется, в консоли тоже ничего не выводится.
версия aiogram - 2.25.1

Comment: Покажите в вопросе код кнопки

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду это?
cmd_arizona = types.KeyboardButton(text='Arizona RP')

Answer (score 0):

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data in ['Arizona RP', 'GTA5 RP'], state=Form.PROJECT)
async def input_nick(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    project = callback_query.data
    print(project)
    await state.update_data(project=project)
    await callback_query.message.answer('Введите ваш ник в формате: Имя_Фамилия', reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())
```

Так как принимается callback, а не обычное сообщение, то должен быть другой хэндлер. Обработка события в функции также немного меняется.